# Groovy override default call method

Tags: gradle, groovy, closures, dsl, gradle-plugin

I have the following groovy class as part of my gradle plugin:

```
class MyClass {
    final Expando someOptions

    MyClass() {
        someOptions = new Expando()
    }

    def call(Closure configure) {
        configure.delegate = someOptions
        configure.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_ONLY
        configure()
    }
}
```

Now I want to user to have the ability to configure this class by adding extra properties to it, but those properties should be stored in `someOptions`.

I tried doing this in the class:

```
def call(final Closure configure) {
    configure.delegate = someOptions
    configure.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_ONLY
    configure()
}
```

The user of the plugin can do:

```
myClass {
    hello='world'
}
```

However, gradle does not seem to understand that the `hello` property does not exist on the `myClass` instance but rather on `someOptions` within the class. Whenever I use the above, I get errors about `hello` not existing in the `MyClass` instance.

How do I do this? Is it possible?

*FWIW, it works in the groovy console, but not in gradle.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any classes you define in your plugin are not directly used in Gradle, but wrapped in proxy classes by Gradle. As an example,

> Gradle will create a proxy class for the actual class implementation and adds (among other things) also a property setter method. The method has the name of the property and has a single argument of the same type as the property. It is different from the `setProperty` and `getProperty` methods already added by Groovy. For example if we have a task with a property with the name message of type String then Gradle will add the method `message(String)` to the proxy class. ([Source](http://mrhaki.blogspot.de/2016/02/gradle-goodness-methods-generated.html))

This is the reason, why you can omit the assignment sign in Gradle scrips:

```
task myTask {
    myProperty true      // uses Gradle generated method
    myProperty = true    // uses Groovy generated setter
}
```

Gradle also adds a method similar to yours to allow the configuration of any object in the DSL:

```
myExtension {
    // this works thanks to Gradle
}
```

Without this proxy method, it would be necessary to use the method [`with(Closure)`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Object.html#with(groovy.lang.Closure)) from the Groovy language for any block:

```
myExtension.with {
    // this works thanks to Groovy
}
```

It seems like this proxy method overrides the `call(Closure)` method of your example.

To solve this, you could use the [`Delegate`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.7/html/gapi/groovy/lang/Delegate.html) annotation in Groovy on `someOptions`. This would make all its properties available to the `MyClass` instance. You could also register `someOptions` as convention on `MyClass`.

**EDIT**

You can see that your method is never called by comparing the stacktrace of your current example and a second stacktrace, after you changed the name of the `call` method and called it explicitly (you need to use another property to get the same exception).

Comment: Thank you again. I eventually had to switch to using a `Map` annotated with `@Delegate` and it finally worked.

Comment: I tested your code yesterday and it worked without a map. How do you use `MyClass`? I guess it gets registered as extension?

Comment: yup it's registered as extension

Comment: If `Expando` is a simple class with a property `hello` and you use `@Delegate` on `someOptions`, your code example should work.

Comment: No actually Expando is a groovy object http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/Expando.html. I should have mentioned that initially

Comment: Ah sorry, I'm not that familiar with Groovy, only with Gradle. But I'm glad I could help you out.

Comment: No problem. Your suggestion led me to the right solution